# How to Access Location.protocol the Angular Way

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, typescript-typings

I am looking for the best way to Access location.protocol in Angular 13.
Currently, I am able to access it with vanilla JS `location.protocol` but I am not a fan of accessing the DOM this way.

When importing and logging out `import { Location } from '@angular/common';` I get:

```
Location: {
  _platformLoaction: BrowserPlatformLocation {
    protocol: (…}
}
```

The issue I've run into is, I am unable to access anything on because of its type, so I can only access it if I cast Location as any.

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';


....

const test = this.Location as any
console.log(test._platformLocation.location.protocol)
```

Which will then log `http:` correctly

What is the best way to do this in Angular without using vanilla JS or bypassing the Typing? I don't necessarily need to use `Location` either. It just seems there should be an Angular way to do this as usually interacting with the DOM directly isn't the best idea

Comment: `BrowserPlatformLocation` is not a builtin class. [See the example](https://angular.io/api/common/Location#example) for initializing the `Location` service, it may help you find the service/strategy you are looking to inject.

Comment: It's just `location.protocol` vanilla JS, no import or injection required. Why do you need an Angular specific wrapper for this? It's guaranteed to work in any browser. It's like saying I want to write `const` in non-vanilla JS.

Comment: Using vanilla JS isn't the issue, I'm looking to see if there is an Angular way since usually interacting directly with the DOM isn't a good idea. There are many little known built in classes such as renderer2 that are used for simple things just for the purpose of not interacting directly with the document.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is really by using `location.protocol`.

Note that the `_platformLocation` as an underscore ('_') before its name. This is a convention used by programmers to note the parameter as private, so it should not be accessed. Thats why you need to cast the variable to any, but this is generally bad practice. See this page for more information on that https://qr.ae/pv2xOg

Comment: I am aware of the '_' meaning private. Thats why I don't want to do this in a hacky way, and I dont actually need to use Location either. It just seems there should be an angular way to do this as usually interacting with the DOM directly isnt the best idea. I'll append my question with that last statement as well